# SlickGrid change Row background color on rollover

Tags: jquery, css, slickgrid

I'm using version 2.0a of SlickGrid for the groupings capability.  Everything works great (with lots of customization).  I'm trying to change the `background-color` for ENTIRE ROW on rollover event.

I've tried this:

```
.slick-row { background-color:#dee0fe; }
```

and this:

```
.slick-row.ui-state-active { background:#dee0fe; }
```

This works on individual cells:

```
.lr:hover { background: #dee0fe; }
```

but nothing seems to work on the entire row and I've never seen an example of this.
I also have the cells set to `selectable:true, focusable:false`.
Seems like it should be easy...

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This works just fine for me:

```
.slick-row:hover { background-color: red; }
```

Comment: It's not really this simple, although I upvoted.  You need to also have: .slick-row { backgroud: white; }  or somesuch.  If you are trying to get a minimally styled configuration to work, you will need both css rules.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, based on the CSS in your question:

```
 .slick-row:hover .lr {
     background-color:#dee0fe;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a go at doing this myself and this is a simplified version of what I came up with. You can tidy this up a lot and assuming your columns don't change it makes sense to cache the inner part of the hash.

Using the API calls it should look something like this:

```
grid.onMouseEnter.subscribe(function (e) {
    var hash = {};
    var cols = grid.getColumns();

    for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; ++i) {
        hash[grid.getCellFromEvent(e).row][cols[i].id] = "hover";
    }

    grid.setCellCssStyles("hover", hash);
});

grid.onMouseLeave.subscribe(function (e) {
    grid.removeCellCssStyles("hover");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is get the collection of cells in the row, and style them on the mouse enter/leave of each cell:

```
$('.slick-cell').mouseenter(function () {
     $(this.parentNode.children).addClass('slick-cell-hovered') ;
});

$('.slick-cell').mouseleave(function () {
     $(this.parentNode.children).removeClass('slick-cell-hovered');
});


.slick-cell-hovered 
{
     background: #EBEFF2 none;
}
```